# assign actions to one sed address simultaneously for match and non-match

Tags: sed

My sed command line script looks like

```
echo "a,b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/ p; /^...$/! q1'
```

I want the script to succeed (return-code 0) if there are exactly 3 letters left, and to fail otherwise.

The slightly nagging part is that I have to duplicate the address `/^...$/`.

I was hoping for something like

```
echo "a,b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/ p ! q1'
```

but that doesn't work, at least not with that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `//` to represent previously used regex

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/ p; //! q1'
$ echo $?
1
$ echo "b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/ p; //! q1'
bcd
$ echo $?
0
```

Alternatively, you can use `b` command to start next cycle

```
$ echo "b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/{p;b}; q1'
bcd
$ echo $?
0
$ echo "a,b,c,d" | sed -ne 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g; /^...$/{p;b}; q1'
$ echo $?
1
```

This syntax will probably work with `GNU sed` only. See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax) for details